# C++ Boost libraries on Visual Studio 2008 64-bit, compiler cannot open .obj file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, 64-bit

I've been working on my C++ application on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, on a 64-bit pc. The program includes and uses Boost libraries, and I've been having some troubles with them.
My current working mode on VS2008 is "Debug x64".

I put my Boost libraries into C:\Boost directory, and included Boost path into solution properties (configuration properties, additional include directories), but I've an error in compiling phase.

`Error  30  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Boost\boost_1_44_0\.obj'`

What does this error mean?

How to solve it?

Comment: How are you telling your compiler where to find the Boost libraries?  For some reason it's looking for one called `.obj` and failing to find it.

Comment: @thehouse I've inserted the Boost directory path into solution properties -> configuration properties -> additional include libraries -> linker.

Comment: Directories don't go there, libraries do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's the answer indeed I think: entering the directory name, the build system will append .obj to it and look for that. Hence the error message shown

Comment: which part of boost are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the comments above more concise, I had the same issue.

By deleting my boost directories from 
*Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies* 
and deleting any boost directories from 
*Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Libraries*.

I'm no longer getting my `Error  30  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\boost.obj'` error.